# R splitting rows randomly in half

Tags: r

In r if I randomly grab half of the rows in a data table how do I grab the other half. I have been using sample_n() to first grab the random rows is their way to index rows to obtain the others?

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with negative indexing:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4),
                 y = c(5,6,7,8))
df
df$index <- 1:nrow(df)
df
df_s <- sample_n(df,2) 
df_s
df[-df_s$index,]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with dplyr::anti_join():

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(c(1, 5, 6, 7, 10), c(3, 4, 5, 1, 9))
sample <- sample_n(data, size = 3)
remaining <- anti_join(data, sample)
```

Anti_join returns all the rows of `x` that are not in `y`. In this case, everything from `data` that wasn't copied to `sample` by `sample_n()` and puts it in the data.frame `remaining`.

The above code returns these three data.frames:

```
> data
  c.1..5..6..7..10. c.3..4..5..1..9.
1                 1                3
2                 5                4
3                 6                5
4                 7                1
5                10                9
> sample
  c.1..5..6..7..10. c.3..4..5..1..9.
1                10                9
2                 7                1
3                 1                3
> remaining
  c.1..5..6..7..10. c.3..4..5..1..9.
1                 5                4
2                 6                5
>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @devan if this worked for you then you can check the answer, showing that it solved your problem. Glad I could help :)